# Change GIT port

Tags: git, configuration, port

When I try: `git pull origin master` I receive the following: `ssh: connect to host localhost port 123: Bad file number`

Now, somewhere and somehow I set up git to use port 123 but that is no longer a valid one. I'd like to change it to port 321.

I went to modify the `~/.ssh/config` file but I surprisingly realized that the file does not exist. I could probably create one and get the desired behavior but my question is: where else can the port 123 has been defined?  How do I change that to 321 without creating a config file?

Comment: Does `git config --list` show any relevant settings?

Comment: yes, i can see port 123 in there, how do i change it?

Comment: You can do `git config --edit` to bring up an editor with your settings in it to allow you to change them.

Comment: thanks, do you know where those properties are stored? Shouldn't they be in a file somewhere?

Comment: The bulk are in `.git/config`, but global settings will be in `~/.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 5):

You can update the port in the SSH URL with `git remote set-url` CLI command. For example, to update the port of the origin remote to port 321 you can run the following:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://user@site.com:321/home/user/repo
```

If you don't know the rest of the URL you can do

```
git remote -v
```

and then just switch the port number.